# How do I aggregate a has_many field in Phoenix / Ecto?

Tags: phoenix-framework, ecto

Say for example I have the relation:

```
Posts has_many Comments
```

I'm trying to do something along the lines of:

```
Post |> Repo.aggregate(:count, :comments)
```

However, Ecto is complaining that :comments is a virtual field, and therefore it cannot count it. What's a good way of fixing this?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want the comment count for a set of posts. If you want the comment count for all posts you can leave out the where clause.

```
post_ids = [1, 2, 3]
Comment
|> where([c], c.post_id in ^post_ids)
|> group_by([c], c.post_id)
|> select([c], {c.post_id, count("*")})
|> Repo.all()
```

This will group the comments by post, given the post_ids, and count how many there are for each. It will return a list with tuples, e.g. like this

```
[
  {1, 10},
  {2, 3},
  {3, 5}
]
```

If a post has no comments it will not be listed in the resultset.

Comment: This seems like an obtuse way of doing it. Can I not take advantage of the fact that these are related in the database?

Comment: Either its two queries, one to get the posts, one to get the comment counts. Or, you can do it in one query by joining the first and the second and populate a virtual field on the Post struct. It's pretty much how you would to it in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here was my final solution, where `link has_many clicks`

```
  def list_links_count do

    query = 
      from l in Link,
        join: c in Click, as: :click,
        where: c.link_id == l.id,
        group_by: l.id,
        select: {l, count(l.id)}

    query |> Repo.all

  end
```